# Elasticsearch aggregation keep whitespaces

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the last version of elasticsearch (6.5.x).
I want to to keep the **full string** for a field in aggregation .

For example : "New York" in aggregation give "new" and "york".
I want to keep "New York".

In old version, we had to use index: "not_analyzed"
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html

I can't find in the documentation of 6.5 something equivalent.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the field as a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatype.